# User not being redirected to user show page upon devise login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

After logging in or signing up, the user should be redirected to their individual show page. I'm using some code from Hartl's guide, but I can't seem to get it to work:

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      redirect_to login_path
    end
  end

private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

end
```

Routes:

```
  devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout',
                                      :password => 'password', :confirmation => 'verification',
                                      :unlock => 'unblock', :registration => 'signup',
                                      :sign_up => 'new' }

  devise_scope :user do
    get   'login',        to: 'devise/sessions#new'
    get   "logout",       :to => "devise/sessions#destroy"
    get   "signup",       :to => "devise/registrations#new"
    get   "password", :to => "devise/passwords#new"
    match 'users/secret',   to: "devise/passwords#create",      via: :post
    match 'sessions/user',  to: 'devise/sessions#create',       via: :post
    match 'users/signup',   to: 'devise/registrations#create',  via: :post
  end

  resources :users
  resources :sessions    

  root 'home#index'
```

My `/views/users/show.html.erb` is just a simple page, just until I can get the redirect working.

Edit:

rake routes

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /login(.:format)             devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /login(.:format)             devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /logout(.:format)            devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /password(.:format)          devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /password/new(.:format)      devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /password/edit(.:format)     devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /password(.:format)          devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /password(.:format)          devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /signup/cancel(.:format)     devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /signup(.:format)            devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /signup/new(.:format)        devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /signup/edit(.:format)       devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /signup(.:format)            devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /signup(.:format)            devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /signup(.:format)            devise/registrations#destroy
                   login GET    /login(.:format)             devise/sessions#new
                  logout GET    /logout(.:format)            devise/sessions#destroy
                  signup GET    /signup(.:format)            devise/registrations#new
                password GET    /password(.:format)          devise/passwords#new
            users_secret POST   /users/secret(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
           sessions_user POST   /sessions/user(.:format)     devise/sessions#create
            users_signup POST   /users/signup(.:format)      devise/registrations#create
                   users GET    /users(.:format)             users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)             users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)         users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)    users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)         users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)         users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)         users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)         users#destroy
                sessions GET    /sessions(.:format)          sessions#index
                         POST   /sessions(.:format)          sessions#create
             new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)      sessions#new
            edit_session GET    /sessions/:id/edit(.:format) sessions#edit
                 session GET    /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#show
                         PATCH  /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#update
                         PUT    /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#update
                         DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#destroy
                    root GET    /                            home#index
```

Comment: Is there anything else in the log files?  Normally if you have a `show` page you'd have a specific route for it, which I'm not seeing above.

Comment: what is the output of rake routes?

Comment: @CDub, the show page should be taken care of by `resources :users`, right?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't `resources :users` automatically use the REST routes (that include `show`)? I'll edit to show the output of `rake routes`.

Comment: if you manually go to `localhost:3000/users/x` does the page show up? also, when you say 'you can't get it to work' - are you getting an error? if so what?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry @dax - missed that :)

Comment: When I login I get redirected to `localhost:3000` with a `uninitialized constant HomeController` error. There is no Home Controller. At `http://localhost:3000/users/1` I see my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the last line of your rake routes output:

```
  root GET    /                            home#index
```

which points to this line in your `routes.rb`

```
 root 'home#index'
```

You should remove that line in `routes.rb` and replace it with whatever you want your root path to be.

Comment: I tried that; I created a `site` controller and the route `root 'site#index'`. It redirects to the index (home) page view (from `/views/site/index.html.erb`). That is the "root" of the site.

Comment: I just discovered the following: while not logged in, I went to `/users/1` and I was redirected to `/users/login`. There, when I log in, I am correctly redirected to the user's show page. My goal is not have `users` anywhere in any urls too.

Comment: if that's the case the routes.rb line should read `root 'site#index'` - routing reads `CONTROLLER_NAME#ACTION_NAME` - like `users#new` or `sessions#destroy`.  As for not having `users` in your urls, that's outside the scope of this question.